# How to stop FEH from pausing my music when turning on

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I am listening to my favorite tunes and decide to play some FEH. I like to play it muted since the sounds got annoying after a while and I am listening to other game music most of the day. But when I turn FEH on it pauses my music. I have silent mode one as well as having all of the sound sliders muted but nothing seems to help. I didn't see any other options which seem rea

This is a minor issue but if there is an simple solution I have missed I would appreciate it.

I am on an android device (Nexus 6 if it matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.xda-developers.com/pokemon-go-audio-focus/

You can do it by following the above guide but with Fire Emblem Heroes instead. Here are the steps if that guide goes down.

1. Download and install USB drivers for your phone . You can do this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb).
2. Download and install the ADB for the OS you are using. You can get it from  [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads/).
3. Turn on USB debugging mode. To turn this on, go to the "About Phone" page on your phone and tap the "Build Number" until developer mode is on. You can then turn it on in Developer Options.
4. Plug in your phone to your computer and change it to file transfer mode.
5. Using Command Prompt, go to the directory of the ADB you installed in step 2.
6. Enter the command "adb devices" and click OK to authorize the connection.
7. Enter the command "adb shell"
8. Enter the command "cmd appops set com.nintendo.zaba TAKE_AUDIO_FOCUS ignore"

Comment: I have done this on my phone and it works for FE Heroes. I have also seen other people on Reddit who have used the same method.

Comment: I'm at work now. I'll try it in a few hours and get back to you.